# Express Helmet - CSS not loading on iOS Safari

Tags: css, node.js, express, helmet.js

I just added Helmet to my Node/Express/EJS project and have been configuring my CSP to enable inline scripts, styles and some external sources. I have it working fine on my Windows laptop in Opera, Chrome & Edge and now I'm connecting on iOS Safari mobile and it appears that no styles are being applied. I am successfully getting Bootstrap (JS for sure, I think the CSS too although it's not 100% clear and I have no console on mobile) but my own stylesheets and scripts are not being loaded correctly.

Here's my code:

```
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'", "*.googleapis.com", "*.jsdelivr.net", "*.jquery.com"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'", "*.googleapis.com", "*.jsdelivr.net", "*.jquery.com"],
        baseUri: ["'self'"],
        fontSrc: ["'self'", "https://fonts.gstatic.com"]
      }
    }
  })
)
```

I also notice that whenever I visit a link on my site on iOS Safari it automatically forces HTTPS when I'm only using HTTP on a localhost server. I have a feeling that this may be the cause of the problem - my stylesheets are referenced as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
```

I think Safari may be trying to find it at `https://(laptop-private-ip):3000/style.css` when it really should be searching `http://(laptop-private-ip):3000/style.css`. Is it possible that it's trying the HTTPS link which is why I can't retrieve my own styles, but can access Bootstrap etc?

And what should I do about it? Any help massively appreciated - I've wasted hours on this.

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. I don't know why this is happening, but two things come to mind. (1) Old versions of Helmet, prior to v5, looked at the `User-Agent` header and changed their response. Are you using an old Helmet version? (2) Could you use the remote Safari debugger to solve your problem, or at least see what the error is?

Comment: Thanks for your response Evan. I'm using Helmet v5.1.0 according to npm. I'm spending some time now to try and figure things out, if I get any logs from the mobile browser I'll be sure to update.

Comment: @EvanHahn had a breakthrough. So I have 2 things that may have been the issue 1 - the Upgrade-Insecure-Requests header could've been forcing HTTPS as mentioned in the post. I tried to disable this with `upgradeInsecureRequests: null` to no avail. I then declared an object of my directives, used `delete options["upgrade-insecure-requests"]` and this seemed to work. However, I then removed this code and it was still working. This made me think that the issue may have been 2 - HSTS's maxAge was still in effect and just expired from last night and now things are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. I am not 100% confident which was the problem due to cache seemingly playing a part but I believe it was one of the following.

- Upgrade-Insecure-Requests
- HSTS